# map is not a function on this.state.items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have my ajax in my componentWillMount then in my render function I do this

```
this.state.items.map(obj => obj.id)
```

but I got error of map is not a function. I suspect it is caused by the first time render issue where items state is not exist yet.

So I check like this

```
    const items = this.state.items && this.state.items.map(
                item =>
                    <li key={item}>
                        <Link as={`/items/${itemId}`} href={`/items?itemId=${item}`}>
                            <a>{items}</a>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
            )
```

why there's still error?

I do have contructor like this

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            items: []
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show the initial value of `items` in constructor ?

Comment: Are you sure this.state.items is an array?

Comment: @AndreiDMS array of object, does it matter?

Comment: that means the response is not an array, can you show the response that you are setting in items?

Comment: @MayankShukla array of object, but does that even matter?

Comment: What does array of object means? It must be an array, it's not important what type of elements it contains

Comment: Run `console.log(typeof this.state.items,  this.state.items.constructor)` and let me know the output of console.

Comment: Better you write your ajax request in ComponentDidMount.....

Comment: The error measns that `this.state.items` is not array. Set breakpoints in your code, step through it and inspect the values.

Comment: Plz show your componentWillMount code

Answer (score 0):

You should set your variable in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            items: []
        };
    }
```

Comment: I have that, wait my items is an array of object, does it matter?

Comment: Show us what comes from the server. Right now, it is either undefined, or something else is returned.